# retrieving variables in an include, from within a function

Tags: php, include

Why doesn't this work? Cannot quite figure it out:

```
function inc($page){
   include(get_template_directory().'/inc/'.$page.'.php');
}


function getPagebyID($id){
   $post=get_post($id);
   inc('page_template');
}
```

---

> [Where "/inc/page_template.php" contents contains:]

```
global $post;

echo $post->title;
```

---

When you use include within a function, the variables no longer work in the include file, even if you use "global". If you directly include without calling the function, then I think it works.

I also tried passing `$post` to the function `inc()` as a parameter, but that didn't seem to work either.

Answer (score 0):

Functions work fine with includes:

> the problem is `echo $post->title;` or `$post=get_post($id);`

Using:

```
$post = "ID: " . $id;
```

and

```
echo $post;
```

works fine, so the problem is within either of those two variables.

Comment: The code making the variables is within another function that calls the function "inc"....could that be the issue?

Comment: Well If the code is like the above then it should work provided the variables you have return valid values. If the code is different then you should post that, otherwise it's anyone's guess what the problem might be.